# Как проверить наличие нескольких элементов одного списка словарей в другом на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано:

```
a = [{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4"}, 
     {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"8", "d":"5"}]

b = [{"d":"444", "a":"1", "c":"3", "b":"2", "g":"r3"}, 
     {"a":"1", "b":"12", "c":"3", "d":"444"},
     {"a":"10", "b":"12", "c":"35", "d":"444"}]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить, есть ли точное совпадение у одного из словарей из списка `b` по всем 3 парам, например: `"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"`, с такими же парами словаря из списка `a`

То есть в данном примере у первых словарей в обоих списках есть точное совпадение, у остальных нет. Нужно в итоге вывести этот словарь из b у которого есть совпадение, т.е. `{"d":"444", "a":"1", "c":"3", "b":"2", "g":"r3"}`
Никак не могу найти правильный синтаксис, заранее спасибо

Comment: как это у остальных нет? А ``"a":"1"``?

Comment: обязательно нужно, чтобы присутствовало три элемента вместе `"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"`

Comment: Ну так добавьте это в вопрос. И все остальные требования, которые не указаны. А то потом еще вдруг что-нибудь выяснится.

Comment: я вроде так и написал в начале. Добавил "всем 3"

Comment: Определитесь, пожалуйста, с метками. 2 или 3 ветку используете? Если 3, то важна ли конкретизация для 3.6?

Comment: версия python 3.7.1

Comment: @ChikChirik сравнивать нужно только словари с одинаковыми индексами в списках - `a[0]` и `b[0]`,  затем `a[1]` и `b[1]` и так далее?

Comment: нет, любой индекс с любым

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном коде сравниваются первые три записи в каждом словаре, если они совпали, то вывод на экран.

```
for x in range(len(a)):
    if dict(list(a[x].items())[0: 3])==dict(list(b[x].items())[0: 3]):
        print(a[x],b[x])
```

Если у вас фиксированный набор ключей, то задача проще

```
for x in range(len(a)):
    if a[x]["a"]==b[x]["a"] and a[x]["b"]==b[x]["b"] and a[x]["c"]==b[x]["c"]:
        print(a[x],b[x])
```

Если требуется совпадение заданного количества элементов, например 3-х, то можно найти размер пересечения двух словарей:

```
def intersection(a,b):
    result=[]
    for elA in a.keys():
        if elA in b.keys():
            if b[elA]==a[elA]:
                result.append({elA:a[elA]})
    return result


for k in range(len(a)):
    if len(intersection(a[k],b[k]))==3:
        print(a[k],b[k])
```

Comment: можно подробнее про первый вариант, пожалуйста. Конкретно про вторую строку. Я пока такой синтаксис не понимаю(( И возможно ли сделать, чтобы проверяло не только первые 3 записи в словаре? так как их может быть сколько сколько угодно.

Comment: @ChikChirik так вы же написали что по 3-м нужно сравнивать. Замените 0:3 на 0:5 если хотите сравнить первые пять записей.

Comment: мне нужно по 3, но не по первым 3.

Comment: Вы напишите четко условие задачи. Например: Два словаря равны если есть точное совпадение трех пар в каждом.

Comment: я вроде бы так и написал

Comment: Не совсем так. В примере они идут последовательно. Имеет ли значение какие элементы совпадают?

Comment: да, извиняюсь. думал будет понятно, отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Добавил вариант когда нужно совпадение 3-х пар.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import product
from operator import itemgetter, eq


a = [{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4"}, 
     {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"8", "d":"5"}]

b = [{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"444"}, 
     {"a":"1", "b": "12", "c":"3", "d":"444"}]

equal_keys = 'abc'
getter = itemgetter(*equal_keys)

for pair in product(a, b):
    try:
        if eq(*map(getter, pair)):
            print("Dict {} in 'a' equal dict {} in 'b' by keys '{}'".format(*pair, equal_keys))
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверить на вхождение словаря в другой словарь можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30818799/5201699) `b.items() <= a.items()`

```
In [1]: {"a": 1, "b": 2}.items() <= {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}.items()                                 
Out[1]: True

In [2]: {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}.items() <= {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}.items()                         
Out[2]: True

In [3]: {"a": 1, "b": 0}.items() <= {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}.items()                                 
Out[3]: False
```

Решение:

```
list_a = [
    {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3", "d":"4"}, 
    {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"8", "d":"5"}
]

list_b = [
    {"a":"1", "b":"12", "c":"3", "d":"444"},
    {"d":"444", "a":"1", "c":"3", "b":"2", "g":"r3"},
    {"d":"444", "a":"1", "b":"2", "g":"r3"},
    {"a":"10", "b":"12", "c":"35", "d":"444"}
]


for dict_b in list_b:

    # Создаем словарь из нужных нам ключей-значений 
    subdict_b = {key: dict_b.get(key) for key in ("a", "b", "c")}  
    #print(subdict_b)

    for dict_a in list_a:
        # Проверяем на вхождение
        if subdict_b.items() <= dict_a.items(): 
            print("Совпадение: ", dict_a, dict_b)
```